# Difference between 'do so' and 'do' without the 'so'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, formality, do

I understand that when I wish to repeat an infinitive form of the verb, it's correct to use 'to do so'.

For example, He wished to leave the house party, and I wanted to (do so) as well. Here simply using the 'do' without a 'so' would be odd, although I understand one can totally omit the 'do so' altogether, in this context.

My question is if the replacement verb doesn't have an infinitive component, is there any (formal vs informal or in terms of usage) difference between 'do' and 'do so'?

I present two sentences below:

1. Historical evidence provides clues for determining when birds evolved and how they did so. (Vs) – I understand this can be written more concisely as 'when and how they evolved', but this isn't my query.
2. The same sentence with the 'did so' replaced by 'did' –... when birds evolved and how they did.

Would there be any formal/grammatical differences between the two structures? Also, in what other contexts is 'do/did', etc., incorrect and 'do/did **so**' is correct and vice versa?